# subset a data.frame based on unique identifiers in another data.frame

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

Lets say we have to data.frames:

```
x <- data.frame(date=c(1,2,3,1,3),  id=c("a", "a", "a", "b", "b"), sum=50:54)
y <- data.frame(date=c(1,2,1,3), id=c("a", "a", "b", "b"))

x
  date id sum
1    1  a  50
2    2  a  51
3    3  a  52
4    1  b  53
5    3  b  54
y

  date id
1    1  a
2    2  a
3    1  b
4    3  b
```

Now, i want to find the row in x that has dates that is not in y, within the same id. In y we have 1, 2 and 3 in id a and in y we only have 1 and 2 in id a. 
How do i identify (and, preferably remove from x) row number 3 in x?

EDIT: I found a (very ugly and slow) solution, but there has to be a better and faster one? Currently im running it on two large data.frames, and first time it took more than one hour. I need to run it multiple times, so any help would be appreciated.

```
z <- data.frame()

for (f in 1:length(unique(x$id))) {  #Run the iteration for all the unique id's in x
  id <- unique(x$id)[f]   #find the name of the id in this iteriation
  a <- x[x$id==id,]       #subset x 
  b <- y[y$id==id,]       #subset y
x.new <- a[a$date%in%unique(b$date),] #find the dates that are in x and also in y
z <- rbind(z, x.new)       #bind the two data.frames together
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you want an **inner join**. You are conceptualizing the problem as *"find rows in X that are not in Y, then remove them from X,"* - this is more commonly stated as *"keep only rows in X that are also in Y."*

There are many ways to do this, it is the default setting for `base::merge`

```
merge(x, y, all = F)
#   date id sum
# 1    1  a  50
# 2    1  b  53
# 3    2  a  51
# 4    3  b  54
```

There are many other options detailed at the R-FAQ [How to join (merge) data frames (inner, outer, left, right)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1299871/903061)

If you do need to identify the removed rows for some other purpose, `dplyr::anti_join` is one way. `anti_join(x, y)` will return the rows in `x` that are not in `y`.

```
library(dplyr)
anti_join(x, y)
# Joining, by = c("date", "id")
#   date id sum
# 1    3  a  52
```

If speed is an issue, the `data.table` solution method [as in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9652931/903061) will be fastest. [This answer does some fairly comprehensive benchmarking](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38130460/903061). However, your code is making enough inefficient steps (growing a data frame inside a loop, recomputing the same `unique` values, sometimes unnecessarily) that my guess is that even `base::merge` will be several orders of magnitude faster.